# SASS: Append class selectors in loop

Tags: css, sass

I want to get the following css:

```
.menu IMG { padding-left: 10px; }
.menu .submenu IMG { padding-left: 20px; }
.menu .submenu .submenu IMG { padding-left: 30px; }
```

So in each loop ".submenu" should be added in the selector and the padding should be updated.

Is there anyway how to do this with SASS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
@for $i from 1 through 3 {
    $class: '.menu';

    @if $i > 1 {
        @for $j from 1 through $i - 1 {
            $class: $class + ' .submenu';
        }
    }
    $class: $class + ' IMG';
    #{$class} {
        padding-left: #{$i * 10px};
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd ideally wish for an if/else block that excludes the first `.submenu` if `$i ` is `< 1`, starting `$1` at `0`

Comment: @Roberrrt, good point, but i could simply loop from 0 through 2, so nested for loop will not execute at first iteration. Updated my answer

Comment: This doesn't work but somehow manages to insert two `.submenu` classes at the first entry. This works though: `@for $i from 0 through 5 {
        $class: '.menu';
    
        @for $i from 0 through $i {
            @if $i < 1 { 
              $class: $class 
            }
            @else {
              $class: $class + ' .submenu';
            }
        }
        $class: $class + ' IMG';
        #{$class} {
            padding-left: #{$i * 10px};
        }
    }`

Comment: @Roberrrt i've not expected from sass to iterate in negative direction. Fixed my code again and tested it this time, thanks